pass std::unique_ptr to std::bind
if i pass simple int or string all is okay. but when i pass unique_ptr it moves inside bind object (bind_f) and i can't call bind_f();
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template <typename F, typename... Args>
void TestF(F&& fnc, Args&&... args) {
    auto bind_f = std::bind(std::move(fnc), std::move(args)...);
    bind_f(); // error: no match for call to '(std::_Bind<main()::
              // <lambda(std::unique_ptr<int>)>(std::unique_ptr<int>)>) ()'
              // [build]   383 |     bind_f();
              // [build]       |     ~~~~~~^~
}

int main() {

    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_unique<int>(11);

    auto work = [](std::unique_ptr<int> val) {
        cout << *val << endl;
    };

    auto work2 = [](int val, std::string str) {
        cout << val << endl;
    };

    TestF(std::move(work2), 10, "ssdf"s);
    TestF(std::move(work), std::move(ptr));

    cout << "done" << endl;

}


Try work(ptr). The whole TestF machinery is distracting from the actual issue in the code.

You might use auto work3 = [ptr = std::move(ptr)]() { std::cout << *ptr << std::endl; }; TestF(work3);

Also see std::forward.

This is because the return object of bind passes it's ordinary arguments as lvalue references to the bound function when called. It doesn't know that you only intend to call it once, and that you want the pointer to be moved.
